# C# Function Encrypt in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, encryption

I want to use **Encrypt(myString)** from C# in JS code.

Is this possible?

I tried something like that:

*In C#*

```
public object IDToUrl(int myNumber)
    {
        return Encrypt(myNumber.ToString());
    }
```

*In JS*

```
var encryptedValue = '<%=IDToUrl(data.id)%>';
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What methodology are you using to serve your HTML? WebForms or MVC? Are you trying to use your `'<%=IDToUrl(data.id)%>';` in a .js page, or in your HTML page?

Comment: WebForms Sir, but I did it, thanks for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code would only work if that `IDToUrl()` method is local to that page.  You don't state what view you are using, but I would solve this with a helper class.

Add a Helper class like this:

```
public static class SomeNameHelper
{
   public static object IDToUrl(int myNumber)
   {
      return Encrypt(myNumber.ToString());
   }
   public static object Encrypt(string s){
      ... whatever code that is required...
   }
}
```

In js:

```
var encryptedValue = '<%=SomeNameHelper.IDToUrl(data.id)%>';
```